# How to change reference category in R LCMM

Tags: r, panel-data

I created an LCMM model in r and then added a covariate to the call using =~classmb. The issue is the model is using class three as the reference class. I want the model to use class 2 as the reference class as it is the largest. I am aware of the relevel function that can be used for linear regressions and was wondering if there was a way to do this for LCMM. [image]

Comment: can you provide a bit more information. As of now, i can only guess you need the function ```relevel()```, you can check the help page here https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/relevel

Comment: Also, please [post code as text instead of images](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)